# How to use Link component inside marker infowindow in nextjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js, marker, infowindow, google-map-react

Hi I am implementing google map in my nextjs app
Here is my map.js component file

```
import { AsYouType } from 'libphonenumber-js'
import { useState } from 'react';
import {get_location_slug} from '../utility/calculate_distance'

const phoneFormat = new AsYouType('US')
const Marker = (props,location) => `
  <div class="max-w-sm rounded overflow-hidden shadow-lg">
    <div class="px-2">
      <div class="font-bold text-base mb-2 text-blue-500">
        <a href=${"/data/"+location}>
          ${props.city}
        </a>
      </div>
      <p class="text-dark-400 text-sm">${props.street}</p>
      <p class="text-dark-400 text-sm mb-2">
        ${props.city}, ${props.stateIso}, ${props.countryIso}, ${props.postalCode}
      </p>
      <p class="text-gray-700 font-medium mb-2">
        Phone: <span class="font-light">${phoneFormat.input(props.phone)}</span>
      </p>
      <p>
        <a class="text-blue-500" href="https://www.google.com/maps/dir/'+${props.defaultLat}+','+${props.defaultLng}+'/'+${props.latitude}+','+${props.longitude}+'">
        Directions
        </a>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
`

export default function Map(props) {
  const [locations, setLocations ] = useState(props.locations)
  const defaultProps = {
    center: {
    lat: (typeof(props.latitude) === "undefined" ? 12.22 : props.latitude),
    lng: (typeof(props.longitude) === "undefined" ? -90.22 : props.longitude),
    },
    zoom: 7
  }
  const latitude = (typeof(props.latitude) === "undefined" ? 12.22 : props.latitude)
  const longitude = (typeof(props.longitude) === "undefined" ?  -90.22: props.longitude)
  function handleApiLoaded(map,lat,lng){
    let infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow()
    let markerCenter = 0
    props.locations.map((location) => {
     let location_slug = get_location_slug(location)
      markerCenter == 0 && map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(location.latitude,location.longitude))
      markerCenter = 1
      let marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: {lat: parseFloat(location.latitude), lng: parseFloat(location.longitude)}, map: map, title: location.name})
      marker.setIcon('http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/red-dot.png')
      marker.addListener('click', function() {
        infowindow.close()
        infowindow.setContent(Marker(location,location_slug))
        infowindow.open(map, marker)
      })
    })
  }

  return (
    <div style={{ height: '100%', width: '100%' }}>
      <GoogleMapReact
        bootstrapURLKeys={{ key: `${process.env.GOOGLE_API_KEY}` }}
        defaultCenter={defaultProps.center}
        defaultZoom={defaultProps.zoom}
        yesIWantToUseGoogleMapApiInternals
        onGoogleApiLoaded={({ map }) => handleApiLoaded(map,latitude,longitude)}
        key={props.locations,latitude,longitude}
        />
    </div>
  )
}
```

As you can see currently I am using **a** tag in const Marker

```
<a href=${"/data/"+location}>
          ${props.city}
 </a>
```

for my map infowindow which is reloading the page, but I want to use **Link** tag so that it won't reload it,In my Whole Application I am using **Link** tag so that it will not reload the page, but just for this marker info window I am unable to do this.
how can I do this ?

Comment: Why are you unable to do this? What if you use `router.push`?

Comment: Its still reloading the whole page

Comment: Does the file `"/data/"+location` exist in pages?

Comment: yes , it does exist, can you share the whole example once how I should do exactly

Comment: Instead of `<a href` use a `<div onClick={() => router.push("/data/"+location )}></div>` You should import `useRouter` from `next/router` and call `const router = useRouter()` at the beginning of Marker component. I'm not sure if this works. if it doesn't, you should create a reproducable example on codesandbox.